# android sample bluetooth chat to serial bluetooth adaptor(rs232) communication

Tags: android, spp

I am trying to communicate wit **serial bluetooth adapte**r from **android sample bluetooth chat application .***.
 i have changed the UUID to:"00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
but even then its saying "UNABLE TO CONNECT"
i'm using **2.3.3 android device** and L*M048 Bluetooth Serial Adapter**

**code is same sample blutooth chat provided by gooogle 
want to know wat changes have to be made to that code to communicate with LM048 Bluetooth Serial Adapter using COM1 port on HYperterminal**

BluetoothChat.java

```
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

  public class BluetoothChat extends Activity {
// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChat";
private static final boolean D = true;

// Message types sent from the BluetoothChatService Handler
public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

// Key names received from the BluetoothChatService Handler
public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
public static final String TOAST = "toast";

// Intent request codes
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;

// Layout Views
private TextView mTitle;
private ListView mConversationView;
private EditText mOutEditText;
private Button mSendButton;

// Name of the connected device
private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
// Array adapter for the conversation thread
private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
// String buffer for outgoing messages
private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
// Local Bluetooth adapter
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
// Member object for the chat services
private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

    // Set up the window layout
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);

    // Set up the custom title
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_left_text);
    mTitle.setText(R.string.app_name);
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_right_text);

    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

    // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
    // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    // Otherwise, setup the chat session
    } else {
        if (mChatService == null) setupChat();
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");

    if (mChatService != null) {
        // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
        if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
          // Start the Bluetooth chat services
          mChatService.start();
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void setupChat() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

    // Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread
    mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message);
    mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);
    mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);

    // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
    mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
    mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);

    // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
    });

    // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
    mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(this, mHandler);

    // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
    mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
}

@Override
public synchronized void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
    if (mChatService != null) mChatService.stop();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void ensureDiscoverable() {
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "ensure discoverable");
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
        BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
}


private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);

        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
    }
}

// The action listener for the EditText widget, to listen for the return key
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener =
    new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
        if(D) Log.i(TAG, "END onEditorAction");
        return true;
    }
};

// The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
            switch (msg.arg1) {
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                mTitle.append(mConnectedDeviceName);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connecting);
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                mTitle.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case MESSAGE_WRITE:
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the buffer
            String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
            break;
        case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
            // save the connected device's name
            mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                           + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MESSAGE_TOAST:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE:
        // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            connectDevice(data, true);
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE:
        // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            connectDevice(data, false);
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
        // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
            setupChat();
        } else {
            // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occured
            Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi" })
private void connectDevice(Intent data, boolean secure) {
    // Get the device MAC address
    String address = data.getExtras()
        .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    // Attempt to connect to the device
    mChatService.connect(device, secure);
}


}


}
```

}

BluetoothChatService.java

```
    import java.io.IOException;

      @SuppressLint("NewApi")
      public class BluetoothChatService {
       // Debugging
       private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";
        private static final boolean D = true;

// Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
private static final String NAME_SECURE = "BluetoothChatSecure";
private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BluetoothChatInsecure";

// Unique UUID for this application
private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
    UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
        UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");


// Member fields
private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
private final Handler mHandler;
private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private int mState;

// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mHandler = handler;
}


private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
    mState = state;

    // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
    mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
}

/**
 * Return the current connection state. */
public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}


public synchronized void start() {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    setState(STATE_LISTEN);

    // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
    if (mSecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(true);
        mSecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(false);
        mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, secure);
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}


@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
        device, final String socketType) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected, Socket Type:" + socketType);

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
    if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mSecureAcceptThread = null;
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, socketType);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(BluetoothChat.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}


public synchronized void stop() {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");

    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mSecureAcceptThread = null;
    }

    if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
    }
    setState(STATE_NONE);
}


public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}


private void connectionFailed() {
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(BluetoothChat.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    BluetoothChatService.this.start();
}

private void connectionLost() {
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(BluetoothChat.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    BluetoothChatService.this.start();
}


private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
    private String mSocketType;

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure":"Insecure";

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                    MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                        NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    public void run() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);

        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                mSocketType);
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void cancel() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "cancel " + this);
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}


/
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi" })
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private String mSocketType;

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {

        mmDevice = device;

        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
        setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                        " socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect " + mSocketType + " socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

**stack flow**

```
10-17 16:31:32.500: E/BluetoothChat(2942): +++ ON CREATE +++
10-17 16:31:32.590: E/BluetoothChat(2942): ++ ON START ++
10-17 16:31:32.590: E/BluetoothChat(2942): + ON RESUME +
10-17 16:31:32.610: E/BluetoothChat(2942): - ON PAUSE -
10-17 16:31:41.450: D/BluetoothChat(2942): onActivityResult -1
10-17 16:31:41.450: D/BluetoothChat(2942): setupChat()
10-17 16:31:41.460: E/BluetoothChat(2942): + ON RESUME +
10-17 16:31:41.470: D/BluetoothChatService(2942): start
10-17 16:31:41.470: D/BluetoothChatService(2942): setState() 0 -> 1
10-17 16:31:41.590: D/BluetoothChatService(2942): Socket Type : SecureBEGINmAcceptThreadThread[Thread-10,5,main]
10-17 16:31:41.630: I/BluetoothChat(2942): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 1
 10-17 16:31:41.630: D/BluetoothChatService(2942): Socket Type: InsecureBEGIN mAcceptThreadThread[Thread-11,5,main]
 10-17 16:31:51.779: W/KeyCharacterMap(2942): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
 10-17 16:31:52.590: E/BluetoothChat(2942): - ON PAUSE -
 10-17 16:31:52.670: D/dalvikvm(2942): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 101K, 51% free   2642K/5379K, external 924K/1038K, paused 37ms
 10-17 16:31:54.250: D/BluetoothChat(2942): onActivityResult -1
 10-17 16:31:54.250: D/BluetoothChatService(2942): connect to: 00:12:6F:01:31:08
 10-17 16:31:54.250: D/BluetoothChatService(2942): setState() 1 -> 2
 10-17 16:31:54.250: E/BluetoothChat(2942): + ON RESUME +
  10-17 16:31:54.250: I/BluetoothChat(2942): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 2
 10-17 16:31:54.270: I/BluetoothChatService(2942): BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:Secure
 10-17 16:31:55.300: D/BluetoothChatService(2942): start
10-17 16:31:55.300: D/BluetoothChatService(2942): setState() 2 -> 1
 10-17 16:31:55.310: I/BluetoothChat(2942): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 1
10-17 16:32:02.369: W/KeyCharacterMap(2942): No keyboard for id 0
10-17 16:32:02.369: W/KeyCharacterMap(2942): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keyc/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

Comment: Can you post some code, and the stack trace of the error you are receiving.

Comment: It worked with changing UUID ... i had set device settings wrong

Comment: @chalukya3545 -- Which UUID you are using now. as I am facing same problem now..

Comment: this "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"